# Kafka Streams Get Client Id in Processor API

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Is there a way to get the client id in a processor?  My thought is it maybe able to be built with info in the processor context?

For example, "my_app-e2e751f2-7c99-484d-9a5b-172de63bc6e1-StreamThread-1"

The reason for this I want to add new metrics to the existing location.

kafka.streams->my_app-e2e751f2-7c99-484d-9a5b-172de63bc6e1-StreamThread-1->*

Comment: You can set the client id in `StreamsConfig`. This way you don't need to retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get the client id in a processor?

You can access the `application.id` (which represents the Kafka consumer group ID used by your Kafka Streams application) as well as the stream task id via the `ProcessorContext`:

```
ProcessorContext#applicationId()
ProcessorContext#taskId()
```

See the Apache Kafka 2.1 docs for more information:

- https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/ProcessorContext.html
- https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#application-id

Is that what you need?